# Celery task with a long ETA and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

RabbitMQ may enforce ack timeouts for consumers: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-modes
By default if a task has not been acked within 15 min entire node will go down with a `PreconditionFailed` error.
I need to schedule a celery task (using RabbitMQ as a broker) with an ETA quite far in the future (1-3 h) and as of now (with celery 4 and rabbitmq 3.8) when I try that... I get `PreconditionFailed` after the consumer ack timeout configured for my RMQ.
I expected that the task would be acknolwedged before its ETA ...

**Is there a way to configure an ETA celery task to be acknowledged within the consumer ack timeout?**

right now I am increasing the `consumer_timeout` to above my ETA time delta, but there must be a better solution ...

Comment: Set `{consumer_timeout, false}` in `rabbitmq.config`.

Comment: sadly, that does not seem to work for me: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/3096

Comment: It does if you use `rabbitmq.config` and classic formatting.
```Config files

 * /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config```

Comment: Hi,

I also wanted to do something similar and have tried something with the "rabbitmq-delayed-exchange-plugin" and "dead-letter-queue". I wrote an article about both and mentioned the links below. I hope it will be helpful to someone.

using dlx: https://medium.com/@anandhu.gopi97/how-to-schedule-celery-tasks-part-1-a1ea7b70b6a3

using   RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin: https://medium.com/@anandhu.gopi97/how-to-schedule-celery-tasks-part-2-320b40d39945

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adjusting the consumer_timeout is your only option in Celery 5.  Note that this is only applicable for RabbitMQ 3.8.15 and newer.

Another possible solution is to have the workers ack the message immediately upon receipt.  Do this only if you don't need to guarantee task completion.  For example, if the worker crashes before doing the task, Celery will not know that it wasn't completed.

In RabbitMQ, the best options for delayed tasks are the delayed-message-exchange or dead lettering.  Celery cannot use either option.  In Celery, messages are published to the message broker where they are sent to consumers as soon as possible.  The delay is enforced in the worker, not at the broker.

Answer (score 7):

There's a way to change this `consumer_timeout` for a running instance by running the following command on the RabbitMQ server:

`rabbitmqctl eval 'application:set_env(rabbit, consumer_timeout, 36000000).'`

This will set the new timeout to 10 hrs (36000000ms). For this to take effect, you need to restart your workers though. Existing worker connections will continue to use the old timeout.

You can check the current configured timeout value as well:

`rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(rabbit, consumer_timeout).'`

If you are running RabbitMQ via Docker image, here's how to set the value: Simply add `-e RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="-rabbit consumer_timeout 36000000"` to your `docker run` OR set the environment `RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS` to `"-rabbit consumer_timeout 36000000"`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, actually i think you would better to use PeriodicTask, if you would like only do it once set the one_off=True.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html?highlight=periodic

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and I resolved it.

With **RabbitMQ version 3.8.14** (3.8.14-management), I am able to send long ETA tasks.

I personaly use Celery to send tasks with a long ETA.
In my case, I setup up celery to add a timeout (~consumer_timeout), I can configure it with **time_limit or soft_time_limit**

Comment: I do not think this solves the problem that is discussed. `time_limit` and `soft_time_limit` are for running tasks where as the issue under discussion is for tasks that are using `ETA` or `Countdown` feature of celery. The tasks are taken up by workers but not acknowledged (since they are yet to be run at the given `ETA`) and hence the problem (newer RabbitMQ doesn't like that!)

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to do something similar and have tried something with the "rabbitmq-delayed-exchange-plugin" and "dead-letter-queue". I wrote an article about both and mentioned the links below. I hope it will be helpful to someone. In a nutshell, we can use both approaches for scheduling celery tasks( handling long ETA).

### [using dlx:](https://medium.com/@anandhu.gopi97/how-to-schedule-celery-tasks-part-1-a1ea7b70b6a3)

**Dead Letter Exchanges (DLX):**
[image]

#### [using RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin:](https://medium.com/@anandhu.gopi97/how-to-schedule-celery-tasks-part-2-320b40d39945)

**RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin:**
[image]

p.s: I know StackOverflow answers should be self-explanatory, but posting the links as answers is long.Sorry