# PreconditionFailed with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am experiencing an issue between `Celery:5.2.7` and `RabbitMQ:3.11` (through `Docker`). My program is periodically sending tasks to Celery, like below:

```
from tasks import getElements

def collectElements(elements):
    for el in elements:
        getElements.apply_async(queue="queue_getelements",kwargs={"elDict": el.__dict__})

collectElements(elements)
time.sleep(600)
while(True):
    collectElements(elements)
    time.sleep(120)
```

Strangely, the queue `queue_getelements` freezes after the first launch of `collectElements(elements)` (After 5 minutes/600 seconds), and the message appears after 30 minutes (Which is the default `consumer_timeout` time):

```
[2022-10-05 02:45:32,706: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: PreconditionFailed(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more', (0, 0), '')
```

I have tried to change the default `consumer_timeout` time in the configuration by increasing the timer (Like seen as a solution [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6760) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907336/celery-task-with-a-long-eta-and-rabbitmq)), but the freezes still happens before the first loop of my program. Celery seems to receive the tasks only the first time in the queue, and freezes afterward. If I relaunch the queue after stopped it, it receives again the tasks that are waiting on RabbitMQ:

> celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -E -Q queue_getelements -c 4

Does anyone experienced this issue before? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.  Please downgrade the version of rabbitmq to 3.8.14 to fix this. Cheers.

[Rabbitmq-celery-Timeout-Solutions](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6760)