# process remind to user on exact date and time in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

So I have notification system in place.For example when sending a task to user, user get a notification within my system. Right now I have only "instant" notifications. so when I send a task to someone, a notification is created in the db, and via web-socket the user is notified with the data of the notification.

With the Reminder I have the problem, that the notification I want to send here is not necessarily "instant". I want to set the date to next Monday on 9 am. so User should receive the notification on Monday 9 am.

Question: Is there an extension in django (or onboard methods) where I can execute stuff delayed? For example, send notification with the following data on Monday 9 am.

Answer (score 0):

[Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) can be used to schedule and defer tasks.

Here's and example of how to schedule for a specific time. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

Comment: Note that, If you are using rabbitmq as broker, you won't be able to run tasks with countdown or eta greater than 15 minutes from now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907336/celery-task-with-a-long-eta-and-rabbitmq

Comment: how can I considering in Django application?